# Powershell (exchange message search)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've literally just C+P [this](https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/powershell/tracking-messages-in-office-365-with-out-gridview) code into my PowerShell, related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/706499/search-emails-by-originating-ip/) question I asked on Super User.

It gives me exactly what I'm looking for but only for today's emails, can someone tell me how to add a a filter for emails the last two months for example? I looked through the code and I can't see anything related to data range so there might be another cmdlet that needs to be ran?

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance at the script you linked, the individual emails appear to be iterated through in a foreach loop that uses the output of `Get-MessageTrace` as the collection of objects to iterate through.  According to [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200704%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), `Get-MessageTrace` has a `-StartDate` and `-EndDate` parameter that you can specify a range of dates with.

So you just need to use those parameters to get a longer range of dates.  Here's an untested example of what you'll probably need to do for the past two months:

```
Get-MessageTrace -StartDate (Get-Date).AddMonths(-2) -EndDate (Get-Date)
```

Edit: According to the parameter documentation, you may have to do some additional formatting after getting the date.  I'm unfortunately not somewhere where I can test this, but here's what it says:

> Use the short date format defined in the Regional Options settings for the computer on which the command is run. For example, if the computer is configured to use the short date format mm/dd/yyyy, enter 03/01/2010 to specify March 1, 2010. You can enter the date only, or you can enter the date and time of day. If you enter the date and time of day, you must enclose the argument in quotation marks ("), for example, "10/05/2010 5:00 PM".

This may not be necessary since you're already passing a DateTime object (the output of `Get-Date`) instead of a string... but worth mentioning, if you simply want to hard-code a string instead of getting the current time.

Comment: Hi the parameters you found show real promise, however I don't not fully understand the code. I'm not 100% sure where I need to add the new paramters in order for the date range to be affected? I mean I don't need to declare them and then call them as variables do I?

Comment: No worries. Try pasting the line I suggested as-is where your existing  `Get-MessageTrace` currently is. Use the script you linked for reference. You don't need to declare the dates as variables because the output of `(Get-Date)` is a `DateTime` object, and by wrapping it in parenthesis Powershell will know to evaluate that cmdlet before using it as a parameter in `Get-MessageTrace`.  Try playing with your script by commenting out any stuff that acts on this data, and just experiment with how you can use the parameters of `Get-MessageTrace` to your benefit.

Comment: I quite obviously tried copying that full string in to the script and I got no results at all ;( - I'll have a play with it to see what I can do.